# Excel-VBA code for counting the distances of a value between rows and calculating its average

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

How to count the distance of a specific value in a cell between rows and calculate its average? I am dealing 3000 row of values or more. It’s hard counting it one by one because not only it changes but it also keeps adding new values. This is giving me a headache. I would truly appreciate it if some Genius could solve this for me in Excel VBA. If someone can achieve this using array formula without helper cells the better.

A short example here:
[image]

Comment: Shouldn't distance between rows 5 and 3 be 2 rather than 3?

Comment: @VincentG it should be 3 sir because i want to count starting from the value it self. if the 1st value is on B1 and the next is on B2 then the resulting value should be 2 since we started counting from the first value in a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I was the "bad guy" last time, I'll provide a workable UDF this time:

```
Public Function AVROW(rng As Range, str As String) As Double
  Set rng = Intersect(rng.Parent.UsedRange, rng)
  If rng.Rows.Count < 2 Then Exit Function
  Dim aCount As Long, aRow As Long, xCount As Long, xSum As Long
  While Not IsNumeric(Application.Match(str, rng.Rows(aRow + 1), 0))
    aRow = aRow + 1
    If aRow >= rng.Rows.Count Then Exit Function
  Wend
  Do
    aRow = aRow + 1
    aCount = aCount + 1
    If IsNumeric(Application.Match(str, rng.Rows(aRow + 1), 0)) Then
      xCount = xCount + 1
      xSum = xSum + aCount + 1
      aCount = 0
    End If
  Loop While aRow < rng.Rows.Count - 1
  AVROW = xSum / xCount
End Function
```

If you run the code step by step, it should be self-explaining.
However, if you still have any questions, just ask :)

[image]

Comment: Everything is fine... You are still welcome ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve this is as below

```
Public Function getaverage(r As Range, a As String) As Double
    Dim avgg As Double
    Dim matchount As Long
    Dim newex As Long
    For Each cell In r
        If cell.Value = a Then
            matchount = matchount + 1
            If matchount = 1 Then
                Start = cell.Row
            Else
                newex = cell.Row - (Start - 1)
                avgg = avgg + newex
                Start = cell.Row
            End If

        End If
    Next
    getaverage = avgg / (matchount - 1)
End Function
```

[image]